# Test multiple apps on facebook

Tags: facebook

I freelance now and I am wanting to set up a Facebook account so I can create multiple apps for different clients under this account, then become admin and roll out the app totheir page.

Does anyone else do this and if so how best is it to set up from the outset as I will need to test without the public seeing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - I do this frequently...

Placing your application in `sandbox_mode` will ensure that only the people who are allowed to see the application have access to it.

You can also add your applications to your own un-published Facebook page, that way no one will be able to search for your page or application either.

A mixture of `sandbox_mode` and an un-published page should be the safe way to go.  Check out the [Application Security](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/) page in Facebook's documentation for exact explanations of `sandbox_mode` and the roles you can give users in your application.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into security and sandbox now. Someone should really do a detailed blog post about this. Facebook documentation is horrendous at the best of times lol